# How to make multi level path traversal faster in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to find all the paths from the leaf node(E) to the root node(A).
(Not for any specific node, so no id or filed filter here)

The data model is as shown in the image.

I used a basic Cypher query to find the paths (A to E):

```
MATCH path=(:A)-[:USE*]->(:E) RETURN path
```

**It keeps running and never finishes.**

I tried to get the paths from C to E using:

```
MATCH path=(:C)-[:USE*]->(:E) RETURN path
```

This is query takes up to 18 seconds to return 18k paths.
I have tried USING SCAN but no improvements in the time.

How can I improve this traversal to return results in less time?
I need to get the results in 4-5 seconds.

**System Configurations:**

System memory is 32GB

Storage: SSD

**Current Neo4j Conf:**

**heap size:** 
initial-12GB 
max-12GB

**cache:** 12GB

Database size: 1.6GB

[image: Data Model]

[image: Query Profile]

Comment: That query plan isn't useful unless you expand all elements to show what values the operators are acting on. Also, when you said you were using scan hints, can you supply what was tried here? Given this pattern you could see if performance is affected by starting at the start or end node of the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DB paths have a lot of variability (e.g., `C` nodes are not always followed by `D` nodes), but you know that you always want a specific path pattern (e.g., `A->B->C->D->E`), then specifying an explicit pattern should be much faster:

```
MATCH path=(:A)-[:USE]->(:B)-[:USE]->(:C)-[:USE]->(:D)-[:USE]->(:E)
RETURN path
```

Variable-length path patterns are expensive, as they have exponential complexity (based on the depth of the path).

[UPDATE]

Even when the DB paths you are interested in do not have any variability (e.g., the path from `A` to `E` always looks like `A->B->C->D->E`), but there are longer paths that include those paths (e.g., if `E` nodes have long outgoing `USE` paths), then a variable-length path pattern with no upper bound will force neo4j to test all those outgoing paths. In this case, if you still wanted to use a variable-length path pattern, then you should specify a fixed upper bound, since you know the exact length of the paths of interest (`4`, in this example):

```
MATCH path=(:A)-[:USE*..4]->(:E) RETURN path
```

Comment: Thank you @cybersam for suggestions.  I tried what you suggested I found the same query plan because my database is more like a tree starting from A to E.

Comment: I tried apoc path expand from E back to C, time reduced by 40-50%. Now I can get the results in 9 sec. Using query:                             
MATCH (e:E) CALL apoc.path.expand(e,"<USE","/C",0,2) YIELD path AS p RETURN p

Comment: Do you think any scope to improve this? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try `MATCH path=(:C)-[:USE]->(:D)-[:USE]->(:E) RETURN path`?

Comment: There are more nodes for label C, number of nodes of type C are ten times compared to E.